# How to return a file from a controller inside an entity?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I tried to return .pfx certificate as bytearray

```
public class CertificateContainer {

    private CertificateType certificateType;
    private byte[] certificate;
    private Map<String, String> authData;
}
```

converting into bytearray

```
FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(ResourceUtils.getFile(certificateType.getPathToCertificate()))
```

And the controller's return

```
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<CertificateContainer> getCertificate(@RequestParam CertificateType certificateType) {
        return ok(certificateService.getCertificate(certificateType));
    }
```

On a client's side, I'm getting String instead of bytes and adding it to an array

```
new ByteArrayInputStream(
                certificateContainer.getCertificate().getBytes()
        )
```

after that, adding into key store and getting exception "stream does not represent PKCS12 key store".
But if I add the same file from the client storage, it works properly. What I did wrong with transporting the file?